# Installing Crystal Reports Runtime on Windows Server 2016

Tags: crystal-reports, windows-server-2016

I'm working to install the Crystal Reports Runtime (SP31) on a Windows Server 2016 machine, and I just wanted to know - is there anything special I need to know about the installation process? Any special steps that are needed that are different from installing on a local user machine? Any known issues?

Answer (score 0):

Just remember that the choice of 32-bit vs 64-bit is NOT based on the platform. Even if the machine is 64-bit, you should still install the 32-bit version if your app was compiled for 32-bit.

Similarly, data connectivity (e.g. ODBC) should be 32-bit if the app was compiled for 32-bit.

Also, be aware that if the machine has another application that uses the Crystal runtime, but from another service pack, you might run into conflicts.